# MySql Concurrency issue

Tags: mysql, sql

I am using this query to retrieve auto incremented key value of "invoiceNo"

```
 "SELECT AUTO_INCREMENT FROM information_schema.TABLES 
 where TABLE_SCHEMA='DB_NAME' and TABLE_NAME='invoice';"
```

and using that value as Foreign Key and inserting into invoice_sub table

[image: Table]

I use following query to insert into invoice and invoice_sub tables

```
  insert into invoice(netAmount)            
  insert into invoice_sub(PK, itemDescr, itemPrice)<br>
  PK= AUTO_INCREMENT value
```

What if two or more users inserting at same time

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't do that like this!

1. Insert into `invoice`. The ID will be calculated automatically.
2. Get that ID [from the last insert](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/mysql-insert-id.html)
3. use that ID to insert into `invoice_sub`

Comment: thanks for quick response, what if another table (example:paymentId of payment table) also accessed at same time, which last _insert will be inserted? paymentId or invoiceNo

Comment: Using `mysql_insert_id()` will return **your** last inserted id.